# How can I vectorize this loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can this loop be vectorized?  Or can it?  I just don't see it.

```
for c in cats:
    df[c] = np.where(df['categories'].str.contains(c),1,0)
```

(Before reading the **full story** below, expect that you will be very tempted to answer what appears to be the a one-hot encoding question with `get_dummies(sep=';)`.  But that is not really what I am asking. What I strictly want answered is the question above - about vectorizing that loop. I included the **full story** for context only.)

**The full story:**

```
d = {'categories': ['catA;catB;catC','catA;catB','catC','catB;catC']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

       categories
0  catA;catB;catC
1       catA;catB
2            catC
3       catB;catC

cats = ['catA','catB','catC']

for c in cats:
    df[c] = np.where(df['categories'].str.contains(c),1,0)
    
print(df)

       categories  catA  catB  catC
0  catA;catB;catC     1     1     1
1       catA;catB     1     1     0
2            catC     0     0     1
3       catB;catC     0     1     1
```

(This is extraneous text added to the bottom of this question so that SO will allow my question to be submitted - to satisfy the requirement for more text in the question.  I certainly agree with that requirement but in this case I think the above text and code adequately describes the situation.)

Comment: `df.join(df['categories'].str.get_dummies(";")[cats])`

Comment: What's the point of using `np.where`?  just use `astype(int)` convert the boolean from `contains`.  You are iterating on a list of strings, performing a `str` method.  There's nothing to "vectorize" here!

Answer (score 1):

Try with `get_dummies`

```
df.categories.str.get_dummies(sep=';')
Out[113]: 
   catA  catB  catC
0     1     1     1
1     1     1     0
2     0     0     1
3     0     1     1
df = df.join(df.categories.str.get_dummies(sep=';'))
```

Comment: Thanks but does not answer my question about vectorizing a loop.